# Which is the best way to handle RTL CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, right-to-left, dynamic-css

Right now I'm working on a bilingual website and kinda confuse about how to handle the RTL CSS codes. I have 2 things in my mind as follows;

**1. Single CSS file - Overriding LTR default codes.**

```
  .content {
     position: relative;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 240px;
  }

  .rtl .content {
     padding-right: 240px;
     padding-left: 10px;
   }
```

**2. Single CSS file - Without overiding**

```
  .content {
     position: relative;
     padding-top: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .ltr .content {
     padding-left: 240px;
     padding-right: 10px;
  }

  .rtl .content {
     padding-right: 240px;
     padding-left: 10px;
   }
```

Using the first method, there will a lot of overrides. Also using the second method there will be a lot of codes in the css file. I know both will do the trick but curious to know which is the best method. Kindly suggest me if there is another method too.

Comment: look at my example http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/UNS5L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a more robust solution, I would suggest you these approaches:

#### CSS Preprocessor

Learn and use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (if necessary, use a plugin like [Bi-App-Less](http://anasnakawa.github.io/bi-app-less/)) and conditionally add the correct stylesheet.

#### Back-end controlled variable

Use CSS mixed with some back-end variable like:

- `direction: <%=rtl%>;`
- `padding-<%=right%>: 10px;`
- `padding-<%=left%>: 240px;`.

#### RTL Tool

Use a [RTLer tool](https://github.com/louy/rtler/).

Comment: In addition to falsarellas answer, by using `SASS` and `Foundation`, you can easily set `$text-direction` to `rtl` and it will make everything `rtl`.

Comment: @falsarella: Thank you very much. Bi-App-Less seems very handy to handle rtl and ltr. Gonna try this..

Answer (score 2):

CSS can display your text right to left with this:

```
.rtl
{
direction:rtl;
}
```

I prefer to handle padding and margins on a single line:

```
.content {
 position: relative;
 padding:5px 10px 5px 240px;
}

.rtl .content {
 padding:0 240px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: see my updated answer. It would help to if you could describe what effect it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing something like this

```
.content {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.content.rtl {
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

try to hardcode the minimum amount of paddings/margins specific to a direction, heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/UNS5L/